# Not to add delimiter after last column while exporting SQL Server data to txt file - c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, delimiter, filereader, export-to-text

I am exporting a table's data from SQL Server to a text file.

I want to append a delimiter after every column except the last column (header + data) but the code I wrote adds a delimiter after last column also.

How can I prevent it?

```
public static void export_to_txt()
{
    SqlDataReader reader;

    string query = "Select * from tablename";
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string strDelimiter = "\t";
    string strFilePath = @"mypath";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (reader = new SqlCommand(query, conn).ExecuteReader())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
                sb.Append(strDelimiter);
            }

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                Object[] items = new Object[reader.FieldCount];

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    reader.GetValues(items);

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        sb.Append(item.ToString());
                        sb.Append(strDelimiter);
                    }

                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (reader = new SqlCommand(query, conn).ExecuteReader())
{
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
     {
           sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
           if( i < (reader.FieldCount -1)
               sb.Append(strDelimiter);
     }
     sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     if (reader.HasRows)
     {
          Object[] items = new Object[reader.FieldCount];

          while (reader.Read())
          {
                reader.GetValues(items);
                sb.Append(string.Join(strDelimiter,item.ToString()));
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.Join` instead:

```
 sb.Append(string.Join(strDelimiter, items));
```

For the header row you could read it into a list or use LINQ:

```
var headers = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => reader.GetName(i));
```

and then use `string.Join`.

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui : for the headers you just need to get them in an IEnumerable first, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
    sb.Append(strDelimiter);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    sb.Append(reader.GetName(i));
    if (i == reader.FieldCount - 1)
        continue;
    sb.Append(strDelimiter);
}
```

Comment: it gives me error `Error 4 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'
`

Comment: @UmmEHabibaSiddiqui updated my answer... not sure why you got that error though.